# Legend properties when legend.only=T (raster package)

Tags: r

When plotting only the legend (of a `raster` object - a colorbar):

```
require(raster)
r = raster()
r[] = 1
plot(r, legend=F)
plot(r, zlim=c(-10,10), legend.only=T)
```

how can I control the legend axis label size, tick length, and other legend properties? I know I can call `par(...)` before the last `plot()` call, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can pass `axis.args` and `legend.args` as arguments to the legend only function call, [as for `image.plot`](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/image.plot.html) in the `fields` package.

For example, to specify tick positions and labels, and to reduce tick label size, the following should do the trick. It will also accept arguments such as `legend.width` and `legend.shrink`.

```
require(raster)
data(volcano)
r <- raster(volcano)
plot(r, col=topo.colors(100), legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
r.range <- c(minValue(r), maxValue(r))
plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100),
     legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
     axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25),
                    labels=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25), 
                    cex.axis=0.6),
     legend.args=list(text='Elevation (m)', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
```

[image: legend only - arguments]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after, but couldn't find.

Comment: Thanks, finally!! R is sometimes so contra-intuitive... why normal plot pars are not working ...

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to work with the 'smallplot' argument in when 'legend.only=TRUE'. Small works from the bottom/left corner of the plot area smallplot=c(min % from left, max % from left, min % from bottom, max % from bottom).

```
# load data & plot
require(raster); data(volcano); r <- raster(volcano)
plot(r, col=topo.colors(100), legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
r.range <- c(minValue(r), maxValue(r))

plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100), legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
    smallplot=c(0,.09, .3,.75)); par(mar = par("mar"))

plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100), legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
    smallplot=c(0.3,0.5, 0.2,0.7)); par(mar = par("mar"))

plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100), legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
    smallplot=c(0.85,0.9, 0.7,0.9)); par(mar = par("mar"))

plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100), legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75,
    smallplot=c(0.7,0.90, 0.05,0.2)); par(mar = par("mar"))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to edit the color of the text in the legend?